# criar mascara customizada

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para criar uma mascara customizada para um determinado campo?
A mascara ficará no seguinte formato: ____OB_____ 
(4 números + OB + 5 números)

A imagem abaixo exibe bem o exemplo que quero seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o pacote NuGet [jQuery.MaskedInput](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.MaskedInput/).

Na *View*:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#OrdemBancaria").mask("9999OB99999");
    </script>
}
```

Normalmente uso o *Bundle* assim:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    // Alguns JS aqui
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js",
                    // Mais alguns aqui
                    ));
```